# What is the proper way to estimate the probability (proportion of time) a rare event occurs?

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution, rare-events, laplace-smoothing

Often, I need to estimate the probability (proportion of time) a rare event occurs. The standard MLE estimate often gives me extreme estimates since the denominator is usually 1, and the numerator is either 0 or 1, giving me either 100% or 0%.

For example, I am trying to estimate the proportion of web referrals as a result of my email campaign for each of my users. Since the events are rare, most of my users usually have only 1 web referral, and they have either 0 email referral or 1 email referral. In such cases, the MLE estimate is quite unreliable.

Are there standard tricks to correct this over-under estimation? Perhaps something like the laplace smoothing? If yes, how should I go about it?

Comment: I wonder if Poisson's rule of succession could help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

Answer (score 1):

Your question is close to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1/82724#82724) about constructing confidence limits when the binomial estimate is either zero or one. But you have multiple users, and want to estimate a small probability for each one.

Then, if you are willing to assume this small probabilities are similar (your users are *exchangeable* in this regard), you can get strength from using all the data at once. In some way you could estimate one common $p$, and then the individual estimates could be shrinked towards this common estimate. That could be done in a Bayesian or empirical Bayesian way. This is also called a hierarchical bayes model.

Or, since you have many users, estimate the *distribution* of probabilities over the users! That leads you into [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model)s.