# How to compare to failure rates when one process has zero failures?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

I have produced 50 units and after testing, I notice that 3 of them have a failure. So I change my production process and produce another 50 units. This time, I detect no failures. Did I resolve the issue? Can I quantify how sure I can be that the problem is solved?

How should I approach this problem from a statistical point of view?

Finally, what if the situation was reversed, i.e. I had zero failures when measuring 50 units but after a change in the process, I find 3 failures in 50 units. Is this same situation as before? Could I conclude that the process is significantly different?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134380/how-to-tell-the-probability-of-failure-if-there-were-no-failures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is certainly a statistical problem. Given two series of outcomes one with 3 failures and 47 successes and one with 0 failures and 50 successes how likely it is that these two sequences came from a "same source" with some unknown probability of generating successes and failures?

This is exactly what statistical tests answer, and that is the p-value of the statistical test.

In this case you should start on the  [chi square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test) but if you read the details of the chi square test, it does not work when when one of the "cells" is lower than 5 (and you have two of them). So you will need the Yates correction or the Fisher exact test...

As for the 2 question, the order is **not** important. Whether you have first the 50/0 or the 47/3 sequences, it does not mater for the statistical test: the statistical tests **assumes** that the two sequences came from the "same" source!

Comment: So I read a little bit about the chi square and the fisher exact tests. If I understand correctly, I should form 2x2 table and the compute e.g. `chisq.test(matrix(c(0, 3, 50, 47), nrow=2))` which gives me (with a warning) a p-value of 0.241. It means I don't have enough evidence to reject the idea that the two observations come from the same distribution. (fisher exact test gives a slightly different p-value of 0.2424). Does that sound right?

Comment: Yep - that is right!