# Which binomial confidence interval is correct?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, meta-analysis, biostatistics

**Background:** I am working with a data set that requires a transformation. It's prevalence data so I have proportions to deal with, and as the proportions are quite low, I'm using the [Freeman-Tukey transformation](http://www.statsref.com/HTML/index.html?freeman-tukey.html). My aim is to perform a meta analysis on the prevalence data.

I have transformed the proportions, and found confidence intervals using the transformed data.

I have a forest plot with CIs calculated exactly, and another with CIs calculated after a backtransformation. The largest difference between the two sets is 0.07, so they are very similar.

My issue is deciding whether I should be reporting the exact confidence intervals, or those that have been back transformed. There are ten studies in my data, so an approximation is not appropriate.

**Question:** In order to gain the correct confidence intervals, do I have to perform a back transformation?

I currently have two sets of answers and I'm not sure of the correct method.

**Example:** Let's say I have a proportion: `123/9876`.

(1) In calculating the exact CIs without transformation, I get:

```
p=0.01245443; LB=0.01036126; UB=0.01484199
```

(2) After transforming the original data, and using `(p-z*SE(p), p+z*SE(p))`, where `SE(p)=sqrt(1/(n+0.5))`,  I get:

```
p=0.224109; LB=0.2043868; UB=0.2438312
```

(3) Back transforming gives:

```
p=0.01245443; LB=0.01035768; UB=0.01474083
```

But which of these three results is correct?

Comment: See this great answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1

Comment: 123/4321 is not 0.01245443.

Comment: Apologies, I initially used an example with 4321 but decided I wanted to make the proportion smaller to make it clear that I was using the Freeman-Tukey transformation. I have edited it now.

Comment: In my real example, I have a forest plot with CIs calculated exactly, and another with CIs calculated after a backtransformation. The largest difference between the two sets is 0.07, so they are very similar. My issue is deciding whether I should be reporting the exact confidence intervals, or those that have been back transformed. There are ten studies in my data, so an approximation is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) is a simple and accurate confidence interval for the binomial proportion parameter, that automatically adjusts near the boundaries of the range.  The coverage properties of various intervals have been examined in [Brown, Cai and DasGupta (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full) and this is one of the intervals they recommend as having good coverage properties.

The interval is constructed as follows.  Suppose you observe $N_1$ "successes" and $N_0$ "failures" giving a total of $n=N_0+N_1$ data points.  The Wilson score interval uses the normal approximation to give the following pivotal quantity:

$$\frac{(N_1 - n \theta)^2}{n\theta (1-\theta)} \overset{\text{Approx}}{\sim} \text{ChiSq}(1),$$

Letting $\chi_{\alpha}^2$ denote the critical point (upper tail area of $\alpha$) of the chi-squared distribution with one degree-of-freedom, and solving the resulting quadratic inequality for $\theta$, then gives the probability interval:

$$\begin{align}
1-\alpha 
&\approx \mathbb{P} \Bigg( (N_1 - n \theta)^2 \leqslant n \theta (1-\theta) \cdot \chi_{\alpha}^2 \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \theta \in \Bigg[ \frac{2N_1 + \chi_{\alpha}^2}{2n + \chi_{\alpha}^2} \pm \frac{n \chi_{\alpha}}{n + \chi_{\alpha}^2} \sqrt{\frac{N_0 N_1}{n} + \frac{\chi_{\alpha}^2}{4}} \Bigg] \Bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Substitution of the observed values of $n_0$ and $n_1$ then gives the resulting confidence interval.  This confidence interval is implemented in various functions.  You can implement this interval in `R` using the `CONF.prop` function from the [`stat.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stat.extend).  Here is the interval you get with your data:

```
#Compute confidence interval using Wilson-score method
library(stat.extend)
CONF.prop(alpha = 0.05, sample.prop = 123/9876, n = 9876)

Confidence Interval (CI) 
 
95.00% CI for proportion parameter for infinite population 
Interval uses 9876 binary data points with sample proportion = 0.0125 

[0.0104489771546811, 0.0148390256803883]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to report the back-transformed ones. This is because the original proportions are very small, you need to transform them and then transform them back into proportions.