# Estimation of variance of mean of Bernoulli distribution, if sample is degenerated

Tags: variance, estimators, bernoulli-distribution

If $X_1,X_2,…,X_n∼Bernoulli(p)$

Variance of the average of $X$ is

$Var[S_x/n]=\frac{p(1−p)}{n}$

But if we have sample, where all $X$ are equal, $\hat{p}=1$ (or zero), and estimation of var of mean became equal to 0. Is it correct?

Comment: What do you want to do with the estimate? Bayes methods is one option, or use the *rule of three* to get a confidence interval, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274855/using-rule-of-three-to-obtain-confidence-interval-for-a-binomial-population.  If that link doesn't serve you, explain why in a comment.

Comment: I think, rule of three is exactly what i want, thank you!

Comment: [Here is a paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27919727.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A99799e01f5e85fc28adfa4ab395c7449) with an extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

When $p=1$ or $p=0$, variance of each individual $X_i$, *mean* of them, *sum* of them, or any deterministic function of them will be $0$ because now $X_i$'s are certain (they become constant), i.e. you know what's going to happen. For example, if $p=1$, then all $X$ will be $1$, and the average will still be $1$. One can tell you the result without uncertainty as I did.

Comment: I think, i need to correct my question: not $p=0$, but $\hat{p}=0$. So, real p probably is not 1 or 0, and real $Var > 0$, but how we can estimate it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the estimate? Bayes methods is one option, or use the *rule of three* to get a confidence interval, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274855/using-rule-of-three-to-obtain-confidence-interval-for-a-binomial-population.  If that link doesn't serve you, explain why in a comment.