# Interval Estimation for a Change in a Binomial Proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution, credible-interval, method-comparison

I'm not sure how to estimate the confidence interval (CI) for a change in a small sample size binomial proportion using the same sample set both times.

I have two methods that I would like to compare (A and B). I have tested both methods on the same sample ($n=28$) from a large population.

Method A gave the correct result 11 times but method B gave the correct result 17 times. I think that this indicates that method B is 17/11-1 = 55% better than method A. As well as this point estimate for the difference between the methods, I would like to understand the uncertainty caused by my small number of samples. How can I construct a 95% CI for the 55% improvement in performance please?

- In 11 cases, both test A and test B worked.
- In no cases, test A did work but test B didn't work.
- In 6  cases, test A didn't work but test B did work.
- In 11 cases, both test A and test B didn't work.

These proportions all relate to the same sample ($n=28$). They are not independent of each other.

Is there a way to calculate CIs that doesn't assume independence please? I would be happy with confidence intervals or with credible intervals and would also be interested in arguments as to why such measures of uncertainty were not appropriate.

Comment: If you really used the same patients both times, then summary results you give are not helpful. // You'd need both results for each patient. // For 6 patients 3 & 5 correct could mean 000111 vs 011111 (2 improvements, so maybe B better) or 000111 vs 111110 (3 improvements and one worse, only 2 agree, contradictory in a way such that maybe both A & B useless). A good start would be to provide relevant data.

Comment: Very good question @BruceET, I have added those details. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is different to the case where the two proportions can be assumed to be independent, here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58667/change-in-binomial-proportion-confidence-interval?rq=1

Comment: Why has this been locked please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap**

I tried a bootstrap. It often threw the error:

```
division by zero
```

I got around that by assuming:

```
infinity = approximately 10101
```

with the resulting estimates:

[image]

*Figure 1, Improvement (I) against Bootstrap Size (BS) for runs = 100*

[image]

*Figure 2, Improvement (I) against against Runs for BS=28*

This gave an improvement after 1000 runs with BS=28 of:

```
55% [14%, 150%]
```

In Python:

```
print('Generate the sample data')
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*11+[0]*6+[0]*11,
                     'B':[1]*11+[1]*6+[0]*11})
print('sample size: ',len(data))
print('')
print('A B X')
print('1 1',len(data[((data.A==1)&(data.B==1))]))
print('1 0',len(data[((data.A==1)&(data.B==0))]))
print('0 1',len(data[((data.A==0)&(data.B==1))]))
print('0 0',len(data[((data.A==0)&(data.B==0))]))
print('')

# Results
I     = {}
Lower = {}
Media = {}
Upper = {}

# Control Parameters
Runs = range(100)
#bootstrap_size = range(len(data))
BS_Max = 100
bootstrap_size = range(BS_Max)

for BS in bootstrap_size:
    #print('bootstrap size ', BS)
    
    # Results
    I_T = {}
    
    for R in Runs:
        
        # Bootstrap
        BooP = data.sample(BS, replace=True)
        
        # Data
        X_11 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==1))])
        X_10 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==0))])
        X_01 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==1))])
        X_00 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==0))])
        
        # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
        if X_11+X_10 == 0:
            I_x = 10101 # approx infinity!
        else:
            I_x = (X_11+X_01)/(X_11+X_10)-1
        
        # Results
        I_T[R] = I_x
    
    # Results
    I[BS] = I_T
    
    # CI
    Lower[BS] = np.percentile(list(I[BS].values()),  2.5)
    Media[BS] = np.percentile(list(I[BS].values()), 50  )
    Upper[BS] = np.percentile(list(I[BS].values()), 97.5)
```

**Coverage**

I think the coverage is around 93%, slightly under the target 95%.

[image]

*Figure 3, Coverage Probability (***CP***) against ***P(10)****

I assessed it with a simulation.

Coverage changes with probability, so it would be good to try it with various values of the probabilities of the four possible outcomes (***P11, P10, P01, P00***). Unfortunately, running many values of each ***P*** would take too long. Instead, I used **MultinomCI** to get the Wilson interval for each ***P***. This gave:

```
      Est   Low     High
P(11) 0.393 0.236   0.576
P(10) 0.000 0.000   0.121
P(01) 0.214 0.102   0.395
P(00) 0.393 0.236   0.576
```

I gave the name ***Prob*** to the vector [***P11, P10, P01, P00***]

```
sum (Prob) = 1
```

I took the range of likely values for ***P10*** and assumed that as ***P10*** increases, ***P01*** decreases equally.

I assessed 4 values of ***Prob***:

```
Prob = [0.3, 0.0,  0.3,  0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.04, 0.26, 0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.08, 0.22, 0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.12, 0.18, 0.4]
```

I ran it with:

```
n       =  28
runs    =  1000
reps    =  10000
```

which took 41.5 hours.

Last, I estimated the 95% CI for the coverage of the 95% CI, again using the Wilson interval.

In Python:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import statsmodels.api
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = time.time()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(11,0,6,11), conf.level=0.95, method="wilson")
"""
ro.r(r_string)
A_C = np.array(ro.r['CI'])

print(' ')
print('Estimate, CI')
print(A_C)
print(' ')

# Control Parameters
n = 28
print('n       = ',n)

nrep = 10 #10000
print('reps    = ',nrep)

runs = 10 #1000
print('runs    = ',runs)
    
P_10s = [0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12]

d_CP = {}
d_Re = {}

for P_10 in P_10s:
    pvals = [.3, P_10, (.3-P_10), .4]
    print('Prob ',pvals)
    print('total P = ',sum(pvals))

    P_11 = pvals[0]
    P_10 = pvals[1]
    P_01 = pvals[2]
    P_00 = pvals[3]

    I_T = (P_11+P_01)/(P_11+P_10)-1
    print('True I  = ',I_T)

    print('Estimate the Coverage Probability using simulation')
    CP = []

    for it in range(nrep):
        
        # Generate the sample data
        li = np.random.multinomial(n, pvals)
        data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*li[0] +[1]*li[1] +[0]*li[2] +[0]*li[3],
                             'B':[1]*li[0] +[0]*li[1] +[1]*li[2] +[0]*li[3]})
    
        # Results
        Lower = {}
        Media = {}
        Upper = {}
        
        # Results
        I_R = []
    
        for R in range(runs):
                
            # Bootstrap size = n
            BooP = data.sample(n, replace=True)
            
            # Data
            X_11 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==1))])
            X_10 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==0))])
            X_01 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==1))])
            X_00 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==0))])
        
            # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
            if X_11+X_10 == 0:
                I_x = 10101 # approx infinity!
            else:
                I_x = (X_11+X_01)/(X_11+X_10)-1
            
            # Results
            I_R.append(I_x)
            
            # CI
            Lower[R] = np.percentile(I_R,  2.5)
            Media[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 50  )
            Upper[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 97.5)
        
        Low = Lower[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
        Med = Media[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
        Hig = Upper[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
    
        # Check whether the interval contains the true value
        if (I_T < Hig) and (I_T > Low):
            CP.append(1)
        else:
            CP.append(0)
    
    end = time.time()
    print('time    = ',end - start)
    print('CP      = ',sum(CP)/len(CP))
    
    # results
    d_Re[P_10] = CP
    d_CP[P_10] = sum(CP)/len(CP)

# CI
CI_Low  = []
CI_High = []
for P_10 in d_CP.keys():
    low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(d_CP[float(P_10)]*nrep,
                                                                nrep,
                                                                alpha=1-0.95,
                                                                method='wilson')
    CI_Low.append(low)
    CI_High.append(high)


print('Plot')
df_G1 = pd.DataFrame({'P_10' : list(d_CP.keys()),
                      'CP'   : list(d_CP.values()),
                      'Lo'   : CI_Low,
                      'Hi'   : CI_High})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Hi', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='CP', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='CP',      linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Lo', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax1.title, ax1.xaxis.label, ax1.yaxis.label] +
             ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

plt.xlabel('$P(10)$')
plt.ylabel('$CP$')

plt.xlim([0,0.12])
plt.ylim([0.9,1])

ax1.set_yticks([.9,.95,1])
plt.xticks([0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12])

plt.grid(which='both', color='b')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Comment: follow up question: what is the coverage? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509227/coverage-of-a-bootstrap-confidence-interval-for-a-change-in-a-binomial-proportio

Comment: I think the coverage is around 93%, slightly under the target 95%
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509227/coverage-of-a-bootstrap-confidence-interval-for-a-change-in-a-binomial-proportio/509548#509548

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** Thanks for additional info. Maybe start with $2\times 2$ table:

```
              A
          ---------
B         OK    Not       Tot
-----------------------------
OK        11      6        17      
Not        0     11        11
-----------------------------
T0t       11     17        28
```

Then a chi-squared test on this table has a very
small P-value, supporting the anticipated lack of
independence in the paired design. [A simulated P-value
is necessary because of the small counts.]

```
chisq.test(rbind(c(11,6),c(0,11)), sim=T, B=5000)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test 
    with simulated p-value 
    (based on 5000 replicates)

data:  rbind(c(11, 6), c(0, 11))
X-squared = 11.723, df = NA, p-value = 0.0009998
```

In such cases, where the chi-squared test requires
simulation, the simulated P-value is often about
the same as for Fisher's exact test.

```
fisher.test(rbind(c(11,6),c(0,11)))

         Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  rbind(c(11, 6), c(0, 11))
p-value = 0.0009334
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.983321      Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf
```

It seems clear that B does better than A, but with only 28 patients and six differences in responses, I do not want to speculate how to find a useful confidence interval for a difference in binomial proportions $p_B - p_A.$ Maybe someone else can answer that.

Comment: I'm asking about the difference in performance, pB/pA-1

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to estimate a CI? The Wilson interval has good coverage for understanding the uncertainty of small n binomial proportions. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469701/interval-estimation-for-a-binomial-proportion-given-a-specific-test-outcome

Answer (score 0):

I can get a 95% CI for pA and pB:

```
pA: 0.398 [0.236, 0.697]
pB: 0.607 [0.338, 0.971]
```

I used MultinomCI which gives confidence intervals for multinomial proportions
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.39/topics/MultinomCI

I chose the Wilson interval because I think that it gives good coverage for binomial proportions so I guessed that it would be ok for this as well.

In Python:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(11,0,6,11), conf.level=0.95, method="wilson")
"""
ro.r(r_string)
R_C = ro.r['CI']
A_C = np.array(R_C)

print(' ')
print('Estimate, CI')
print(A_C)
print(' ')

# Nomeclature: the estimate of A=1, B=1 with a 95% CI is E_11(L_11,H_11)
E_11 = A_C[0][0]
E_10 = A_C[1][0]
E_01 = A_C[2][0]
E_00 = A_C[3][0]

L_11 = A_C[0][1]
L_10 = A_C[1][1]
L_01 = A_C[2][1]
L_00 = A_C[3][1]

H_11 = A_C[0][2]
H_10 = A_C[1][2]
H_01 = A_C[2][2]
H_00 = A_C[3][2]

print('sum prob = 1: ', (E_11+E_10+E_01+E_00))
print(' ')

p_A = E_11 + E_10
p_B = E_11 + E_01

CI_A = [(L_11 + L_10), (H_11 + H_10)]
CI_B = [(L_11 + L_01), (H_11 + H_01)]

print('pA: ', p_A)
print('CI_A: ', CI_A)
print(' ')
print('pB: ', p_B)
print('CI_B: ', CI_B)
print(' ')
print('Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1: ', p_B/p_A-1)
```

Now to try and get a 95% CI for:

```
Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
```

I think that I first need to fit skew normal distributions to pA and pB:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pA = 0.398
pB = 0.607

CI_A = [0.236,0.697]
CI_B = [0.338,0.971]

print('fit a distribution...')
def fun(z):
    Skew, Scale, loc = z
    
    lst = skewnorm.rvs(a=Skew,
                 loc=loc,
                 scale=Scale,
                 size=1000)
    
    lst=lst.tolist()
    
    #mean = sum(lst)/len(lst)
    median = np.percentile(lst, 50)
    #mode = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
    
    CI = [np.percentile(lst, 2.5),
          np.percentile(lst, 97.5)]
    
    # Error
    Me_E = median - pB
    Lo_E = CI[0] - CI_B[0]
    Hi_E = CI[1] - CI_B[1]
    error = Me_E**2 + Lo_E**2 + Hi_E**2
    return error

# Bounds of Skew, Scale & loc
bounds = ((-1,1),(0.1,1),(0,1))

maxiter = 5000

# Optimiser
DE = differential_evolution(fun,bounds,maxiter=maxiter)
print('success = ',DE.success)
print(DE.message)

Skew  = DE.x[0]
Scale = DE.x[1]
loc   = DE.x[2]
print('skewness parameter = ',Skew)
print('scale = ',Scale)
print('loc = ',loc)

print('Sampling from the skew normal distribution')
lst = skewnorm.rvs(a=Skew,
                 loc=loc,
                 scale=Scale,
                 size=1000)

lst=lst.tolist()
mode = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
print('mode = ',mode)

mean = sum(lst)/len(lst)
print('mean = ',mean)

median = np.percentile(lst, 50)
print('median = ',median)

CI = [np.percentile(lst, 2.5),
      np.percentile(lst, 97.5)]
print('CI = ',CI)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hist(lst)
plt.show()
```

That gives distribution parameters that give almost the same pA & pB:

```
pA: 0.423 [0.205, 0.642]
pB: 0.607 [0.336, 0.928]
```

[image]

*Figure 1, pA and pB*

Next, I combine the two distributions to get the CI for Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

A_ske =  0.9139952525939643
A_sca =  0.13849932254197161
A_loc =  0.3500567328083086
B_ske =  0.9960244237545532
B_sca =  0.18411099887378107
B_loc =  0.5126020868512271

Step = 0.001
ExeS = np.linspace(0+Step,1-Step,1/Step-1)

print('Inverse CDF transform')
A_val = skewnorm.ppf(q=ExeS, a=A_ske, loc=A_loc, scale=A_sca)
B_val = skewnorm.ppf(q=ExeS, a=B_ske, loc=B_loc, scale=B_sca)

# Improvement
Improv = np.divide(B_val,A_val)
Improv = Improv -1

CI = [np.percentile(Improv, 2.5),
      np.percentile(Improv, 97.5)]
print('CI = ',CI)

A_PDF = {}
B_PDF = {}
for x in ExeS:
    A_PDF[x] = skewnorm.pdf(x=x, a=A_ske, loc=A_loc, scale=A_sca)
    B_PDF[x] = skewnorm.pdf(x=x, a=B_ske, loc=B_loc, scale=B_sca)

# Dict to Lists
labels, A_data = [*zip(*A_PDF.items())]
labels, B_data = [*zip(*B_PDF.items())]

# Plot
ax.plot(ExeS, A_data, label='A',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(ExeS, B_data, label='B',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

legend = ax.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.6, -.3, 1, 1),
           fancybox=True, shadow=False,
           framealpha=1, fontsize=22)
plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize=22)

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$P$')
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b')
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,4])

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

This method assumes that the sample is just as representative of the population for method A as it is for method B. This is the other extreme from assuming independence.

This gave a different improvement CI each time I ran it:

```
[40%,62%]
[41%,60%]
[41%,49%]
[43%,68%]
[39%,48%]
```

Comment: I think the inconsistency might be caused where I fit a distribution to pA and pB?

Comment: I've tried to code a less round the houses approach to the non-bootstrap technique https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155480/inverse-cdf-transform-of-the-wilson-interval

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting

```
I = 52% [39%, 55%]
```

when I make the assumption that the sample is just as representative of the population for method A as it is for method B. This is the other extreme from assuming independence.

***multinomCI*** gives the Wilson CI for ***P11, P10, P01, P00***.

I want to get ***P11, P10, P01, P00*** for a given location in probability space (***u***)

```
0 < u < 1
```

I assume that the CI is about symmetric and that therefore:

[image]

I varied the step size (***S***) for how many equally distributed samples I took from ***u***

```
u = [S to 1-S, step S]
```

This gave:

[image]

*Figure 1, Improvement ***(I)*** against step size ***(S)****

In python:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

print('Confidence Level (CL) = fun(u), assuming symmetry')
def C_L(u):
    if u >= 0.5:
        return 2*(u-0.5)
    else:
        return -2*(u-0.5)

print('Vary u')
steps = [1e-1,2e-2,1e-2,2e-3,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5]

# CI(I) for various steps
CI_I = {}

for step in steps:
    Ues = np.linspace(step,1-step,int(1/step))

    # Vary the CL
    CLs = [C_L(element) for element in Ues]

    CIes = {}
    P11s = {}
    P10s = {}
    P01s = {}
    P00s = {}
    pA_s = {}
    pB_s = {}
    I_es = {}

    for u in Ues:
        
        # CL
        CL = C_L(u)
        
        # CI (P11, P10, P01, P00)
        r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(11,0,6,11), conf.level=CL, method="wilson")
        """.replace('CL',str(CL))
        ro.r(r_string)
        CIes[CL] = np.array(ro.r['CI'])
        
        # P11
        if u >= 0.5:
            P11s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][0])
        else:
            P11s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][0])
        
        # P10
        if u >= 0.5:
            P10s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][1])
        else:
            P10s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][1])
        
        # P01
        if u >= 0.5:
            P01s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][2])
        else:
            P01s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][2])
        
        # P00
        if u >= 0.5:
            P00s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][3])
        else:
            P00s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][3])
        
        # pA = P_11 + P_10
        pA_s[u] = P11s[u] + P10s[u]
        
        # pB = P_11 + P_01
        pB_s[u] = P11s[u] + P01s[u]
        
        # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
        I_es[u] = pB_s[u]/pA_s[u]-1
    
    # CI(I)
    CI_I[step] = [np.percentile(list(I_es.values()),  2.5),
                  np.percentile(list(I_es.values()), 50),
                  np.percentile(list(I_es.values()), 97.5)]
    
print('CI_I = ',CI_I)

# Dict to Lists
labels, CI_data = [*zip(*CI_I.items())]

Low = [item[0] for item in CI_data]
Med = [item[1] for item in CI_data]
H_i = [item[2] for item in CI_data]

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(steps, Low, linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')
ax.plot(steps, Med, linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(steps, H_i, linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

plt.xlabel('$S$')
plt.ylabel('$I$')
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b')
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlim([min(steps),max(steps)])
plt.ylim([0.3,0.6])

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

***Coverage***

I think the coverage is around 32%, vastly under the target 95%.

[image]

*Figure 2, Coverage Probability ***(CP)*** against ***P(10)****

I assessed it with a simulation, using the same approach as for the Bootstrap answer. With 10,000 samples for each of the same 4 P(10) values that I used to asses the bootstrap technique it took 32 hours to run.

In python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import pickle
import statsmodels.api
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

start = time.time()

print('Control Parameters')
n = 28
print('sample size (n) = ',n)

nrep = 10000
print('coverage sample size = ',nrep)

step = 1e-4
print('Probability space step size = ',step)

print('Equal points in probability space: 0 < u < 1')
Ues = np.linspace(step,1-step,int(1/step))

print('Confidence Level (CL) = fun(u), assuming symmetry')
def C_L(u):
    if u >= 0.5:
        return  2*(u-0.5)
    else:
        return -2*(u-0.5)
    
d_CP = {}
d_Re = {}
CI_I = {}

P_10s = [0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12]

for P_10 in P_10s:
    pvals = [.3, P_10, (.3-P_10), .4]
    print('Prob ',pvals)
    print('total P = ',sum(pvals))
    
    P11 = pvals[0]
    P10 = pvals[1]
    P01 = pvals[2]
    P00 = pvals[3]

    I_T = (P11+P01)/(P11+P10)-1
    print('True I  = ',I_T)

    print('Estimate the Coverage Probability using simulation')
    CP = []

    for it in range(nrep):
        
        # Generate sample data
        ExeS = np.random.multinomial(n, pvals)
    
        CIes = {}
        P11s = {}
        P10s = {}
        P01s = {}
        P00s = {}
        pA_s = {}
        pB_s = {}
        I_es = {}
        
        for u in Ues:
                
                # CL
                CL = C_L(u)
                
                # CI (P11, P10, P01, P00)
                r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(P1,P2,P3,P4), conf.level=CL, method="wilson")
                """.replace('CL',str(CL)).replace('P1',str(ExeS[0])).replace('P2',str(ExeS[1])).replace('P3',str(ExeS[2])).replace('P4',str(ExeS[3]))
                ro.r(r_string)
                
                CIes[CL] = np.array(ro.r['CI'])
                
                # P11
                if u >= 0.5:
                    P11s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][0])
                else:
                    P11s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][0])
                
                # P10
                if u >= 0.5:
                    P10s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][1])
                else:
                    P10s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][1])
                
                # P01
                if u >= 0.5:
                    P01s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][2])
                else:
                    P01s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][2])
                
                # P00
                if u >= 0.5:
                    P00s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,2][3])
                else:
                    P00s[u] = (CIes[CL][:,1][3])
                
                # pA = P_11 + P_10
                pA_s[u] = P11s[u] + P10s[u]
                
                # pB = P_11 + P_01
                pB_s[u] = P11s[u] + P01s[u]
                
                # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
                I_es[u] = pB_s[u]/pA_s[u]-1
            
        # CI(I)
        CI_I[it] = [np.percentile(list(I_es.values()),  2.5),
                    np.percentile(list(I_es.values()), 50),
                    np.percentile(list(I_es.values()), 97.5)]
            


        Low = CI_I[it][0]
        Med = CI_I[it][1]
        Hig = CI_I[it][2]
    
        # Check whether the interval contains the true value
        if (I_T < Hig) and (I_T > Low):
            CP.append(1)
        else:
            CP.append(0)
    
    # results
    d_Re[P_10] = CP
    d_CP[P_10] = sum(CP)/len(CP)
    
    end = time.time()
    print('time    = ',end - start)

# CI
CI_Low  = []
CI_High = []
for P_10 in d_CP.keys():
    low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(d_CP[float(P_10)]*nrep,
                                                                nrep,
                                                                alpha=1-0.95,
                                                                method='wilson')
    CI_Low.append(low)
    CI_High.append(high)


print('Plot')
df_G1 = pd.DataFrame({'P_10' : list(d_CP.keys()),
                      'CP'   : list(d_CP.values()),
                      'Lo'   : CI_Low,
                      'Hi'   : CI_High})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Hi', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='CP', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='CP',      linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Lo', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax1.title, ax1.xaxis.label, ax1.yaxis.label] +
             ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

plt.xlabel('$P(10)$')
plt.ylabel('$CP$')

plt.xlim([0,0.12])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.xticks([0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12])

plt.grid(which='both', color='b')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the question states that

*These proportions all relate to the same sample (n=28). They are not independent of each other.*

However, if we were to assume ***independence***, then we could use the approach of

*Newcombe, R.G., 1998. Interval estimation for the difference between independent proportions: comparison of eleven methods. Statistics in medicine, 17(8), pp.873-890.*

Who presents

*APPENDIX I: MULTIPLICATIVE SCALE SYMMETRY OF CONDITIONAL INTERVALS DERIVED FROM THE WILSON SCORE INTERVAL*

In Newcombe, 1998's notation, if:

```
CI [f/(f+g)] = [L,U]
```

Then:

```
CI [f/g] = [L/(1-L),U/(1-U)]
```

In the case in this question, this gives:

```
I = 55% [-26%, 224%]
```

In python:

```
import statsmodels.api

x1 = 17
x2 = 11
CL = 0.95
n  = x1+x2

P_E = x1/(n-x1)       -1
print('Point Estimate = ',P_E)

low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(x1, n, alpha=1-CL, method='wilson')

L_1 = low  / (1-low)  -1
H_1 = high / (1-high) -1
print('CI = ',L_1, H_1)
```

**Coverage**

I think the coverage is around 99.88%, vastly over the target 95%.

[image]

*Figure 1, Coverage Probability ***(CP)*** against ***P(10)****

I assessed it with a simulation, using the same approach as for the Bootstrap answer. With 100,000 samples for each of the same 4 P(10) values that I used to asses the bootstrap technique it took 41 seconds to run.

In python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import statsmodels.api
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 28
print('sample size (n) = ',n)

nrep = 100000
print('coverage sample size = ',nrep)

CL = 0.95
print('Confidence Level = ',CL)

start = time.time()

d_CP = {}
d_Re = {}

P_10s = [0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12]

for P_10 in P_10s:
    pvals = [.3, P_10, (.3-P_10), .4]
    print('Prob ',pvals)
    print('total P = ',sum(pvals))
    
    P11 = pvals[0]
    P10 = pvals[1]
    P01 = pvals[2]
    P00 = pvals[3]

    I_T = (P11+P01)/(P11+P10)-1
    print('True I  = ',I_T)

    print('Estimate the Coverage Probability using simulation')
    CP = []

    for it in range(nrep):
        
        # Generate sample data
        ExeS = np.random.multinomial(n, pvals)
        
        x11 = ExeS[0]
        x10 = ExeS[1]
        x01 = ExeS[2]
        x00 = ExeS[3]
    
        low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint((x11+x01), (x11*2+x10+x01), alpha=1-CL, method='wilson')
        L_1 = low  / (1-low)  -1
        H_1 = high / (1-high) -1
        
        # Check whether the interval contains the true value
        if (I_T < H_1) and (I_T > L_1):
            CP.append(1)
        else:
            CP.append(0)
    
    # results
    d_Re[P_10] = CP
    d_CP[P_10] = sum(CP)/len(CP)
    print('CP = ',d_CP[P_10])
    
    end = time.time()
    print('time = ',end - start)

# CI
CI_Low  = []
CI_High = []
for P_10 in d_CP.keys():
    low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(d_CP[float(P_10)]*nrep,
                                                                nrep,
                                                                alpha=1-0.95,
                                                                method='wilson')
    CI_Low.append(low)
    CI_High.append(high)


print('Plot')
df_G1 = pd.DataFrame({'P_10' : list(d_CP.keys()),
                      'CP'   : list(d_CP.values()),
                      'Lo'   : CI_Low,
                      'Hi'   : CI_High})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Hi', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='CP', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='CP',      linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Lo', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax1.title, ax1.xaxis.label, ax1.yaxis.label] +
             ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

plt.xlabel('$P(10)$')
plt.ylabel('$CP$')

plt.xlim([0,0.12])
plt.ylim([0.998,1])
plt.xticks([0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12])
plt.yticks([0.998,0.999,1])

plt.grid(which='both', color='b')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```