# Coverage of a Bootstrap Confidence Interval for a Change in a Binomial Proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, bootstrap, multinomial-distribution, coverage-probability

How can I estimate the coverage of a bootstrap confidence interval for a change in a binomial proportion please?

For example, if the results from two tests (***A*** and ***B***) are:

```
              A
          ---------
B         OK    Not       Tot
-----------------------------
OK        11      6        17      
Not        0     11        11
-----------------------------
T0t       11     17        28
```

Then I can estimate improvement (***I***):

```
Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
```

using a bootstrap technique defined by the Python code below.

```
1000 runs
bootstrap size = 28
```

This gave an estimate and a 95% CI of ***I***:

```
I = 55% [14%, 150%]
```

How can I get the **coverage** of that **CI** please?

In Python:

````
print('Generate the sample data')
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*11+[0]*6+[0]*11,
                     'B':[1]*11+[1]*6+[0]*11})
print('sample size: ',len(data))
print('')
print('A B X')
print('1 1',len(data[((data.A==1)&(data.B==1))]))
print('1 0',len(data[((data.A==1)&(data.B==0))]))
print('0 1',len(data[((data.A==0)&(data.B==1))]))
print('0 0',len(data[((data.A==0)&(data.B==0))]))
print('')

# Results
Lower = {}
Media = {}
Upper = {}

# Control Parameters
Runs_Max = 1000
Runs = range(Runs_Max)

BS = len(data)
print('bootstrap size: ',BS)

# Results
I_R = []
    
for R in Runs:
        
    # Bootstrap
    BooP = data.sample(BS, replace=True)
    
    # Data
    X_11 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==1))])
    X_10 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==0))])
    X_01 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==1))])
    X_00 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==0))])
    
    # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
    if X_11+X_10 == 0:
        I_x = 10101 # approx infinity!
    else:
        I_x = (X_11+X_01)/(X_11+X_10)-1
    
    # Results
    I_R.append(I_x)
    
    # CI
    Lower[R] = np.percentile(I_R,  2.5)
    Media[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 50  )
    Upper[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 97.5)

Low = Lower[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
Med = Media[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
Hig = Upper[max(list(Lower.keys()))]

print('I = ',Med,Low,Hig)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the coverage is around 93%, slightly under the target 95%.

[image]

*Figure 1, Coverage Probability (***CP***) against ***P(10)****

I assessed it with a simulation.

Coverage changes with probability, so it would be good to try it with various values of the probabilities of the four possible outcomes (***P11, P10, P01, P00***). Unfortunately, running many values of each ***P*** would take too long. Instead, I used **MultinomCI** to get the Wilson interval for each ***P***. This gave:

```
      Est   Low     High
P(11) 0.393 0.236   0.576
P(10) 0.000 0.000   0.121
P(01) 0.214 0.102   0.395
P(00) 0.393 0.236   0.576
```

I gave the name ***Prob*** to the vector [***P11, P10, P01, P00***]

```
sum (Prob) = 1
```

I took the range of likely values for ***P10*** and assumed that as ***P10*** increases, ***P01*** decreases equally.

I assessed 4 values of ***Prob***:

```
Prob = [0.3, 0.0,  0.3,  0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.04, 0.26, 0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.08, 0.22, 0.4]
Prob = [0.3, 0.12, 0.18, 0.4]
```

I ran it with:

```
n       =  28
runs    =  1000
reps    =  10000
```

which took 41.5 hours.

Last, I estimated the 95% CI for the coverage of the 95% CI, again using the Wilson interval.

In Python:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import statsmodels.api
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = time.time()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(11,0,6,11), conf.level=0.95, method="wilson")
"""
ro.r(r_string)
A_C = np.array(ro.r['CI'])

print(' ')
print('Estimate, CI')
print(A_C)
print(' ')

# Control Parameters
n = 28
print('n       = ',n)

nrep = 10 #10000
print('reps    = ',nrep)

runs = 10 #1000
print('runs    = ',runs)
    
P_10s = [0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12]

d_CP = {}
d_Re = {}

for P_10 in P_10s:
    pvals = [.3, P_10, (.3-P_10), .4]
    print('Prob ',pvals)
    print('total P = ',sum(pvals))

    P_11 = pvals[0]
    P_10 = pvals[1]
    P_01 = pvals[2]
    P_00 = pvals[3]

    I_T = (P_11+P_01)/(P_11+P_10)-1
    print('True I  = ',I_T)

    print('Estimate the Coverage Probability using simulation')
    CP = []

    for it in range(nrep):
        
        # Generate the sample data
        li = np.random.multinomial(n, pvals)
        data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*li[0] +[1]*li[1] +[0]*li[2] +[0]*li[3],
                             'B':[1]*li[0] +[0]*li[1] +[1]*li[2] +[0]*li[3]})
    
        # Results
        Lower = {}
        Media = {}
        Upper = {}
        
        # Results
        I_R = []
    
        for R in range(runs):
                
            # Bootstrap size = n
            BooP = data.sample(n, replace=True)
            
            # Data
            X_11 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==1))])
            X_10 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==1)&(BooP.B==0))])
            X_01 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==1))])
            X_00 = len(BooP[((BooP.A==0)&(BooP.B==0))])
        
            # Improvement (I) = pB/pA-1
            if X_11+X_10 == 0:
                I_x = 10101 # approx infinity!
            else:
                I_x = (X_11+X_01)/(X_11+X_10)-1
            
            # Results
            I_R.append(I_x)
            
            # CI
            Lower[R] = np.percentile(I_R,  2.5)
            Media[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 50  )
            Upper[R] = np.percentile(I_R, 97.5)
        
        Low = Lower[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
        Med = Media[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
        Hig = Upper[max(list(Lower.keys()))]
    
        # Check whether the interval contains the true value
        if (I_T < Hig) and (I_T > Low):
            CP.append(1)
        else:
            CP.append(0)
    
    end = time.time()
    print('time    = ',end - start)
    print('CP      = ',sum(CP)/len(CP))
    
    # results
    d_Re[P_10] = CP
    d_CP[P_10] = sum(CP)/len(CP)

# CI
CI_Low  = []
CI_High = []
for P_10 in d_CP.keys():
    low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(d_CP[float(P_10)]*nrep,
                                                                nrep,
                                                                alpha=1-0.95,
                                                                method='wilson')
    CI_Low.append(low)
    CI_High.append(high)


print('Plot')
df_G1 = pd.DataFrame({'P_10' : list(d_CP.keys()),
                      'CP'   : list(d_CP.values()),
                      'Lo'   : CI_Low,
                      'Hi'   : CI_High})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Hi', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='CP', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='CP',      linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df_G1.plot(x='P_10', y='Lo', legend=False, ax=ax1, label='95% CI',  linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='--')

for item in ([ax1.title, ax1.xaxis.label, ax1.yaxis.label] +
             ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

plt.xlabel('$P(10)$')
plt.ylabel('$CP$')

plt.xlim([0,0.12])
plt.ylim([0.9,1])

ax1.set_yticks([.9,.95,1])
plt.xticks([0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12])

plt.grid(which='both', color='b')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4,4)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Comment: Anyone know why it under covers please?