# Confidence intervals for binomial generalised linear model with cauchit link function

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, binary-data, ggplot2, link-function

The correct way to calculate a confidence interval (CI) for a generalised linear model (GLM) and avoid the problems of [normal approximation intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) has been adequately discussed by Gavin Simpson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423325/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-logistic-regression/14424417#14424417), [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/01/glm-prediction-intervals-i/) and [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2018/12/10/confidence-intervals-for-glms/). However, the binomial examples provided always concern the `logit` link function, i.e. logistic regression. I would like to model my data using the `cauchit` link function, which is based on the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution): $y = \frac{tan^{-1}(ax + b)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}$. This link function is rarely used but provides an exceptionally good fit in my case. So I tried Gavin Simpson's method on a `cauchit` binomial GLM. Here is a minimal reproducible example in `R` using [these data](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/assets/datasets/darlingtonia.csv).

```r
wasp <- read.csv('http://bit.ly/cobralily', skip = 1)
mod <- glm(visited ~ leafHeight, data = wasp, 
                     family = binomial(link = "cauchit"))
summary(mod)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# (Intercept) -9.28969    4.82027  -1.927   0.0540 .
# leafHeight   0.14928    0.07786   1.917   0.0552 .

new <- with(wasp, data.frame(leafHeight = seq(min(leafHeight), 
                             max(leafHeight), by = 1)))
# predictions on response scale
res.pred <- predict(mod, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE, 
                    newdata = new) 
# predictions on link scale
link.pred <- predict(mod, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE, newdata = new) 
inv <- family(mod)$linkinv # inverse of the cauchit link function
# fit
new$fit <- res.pred$fit # same as inv(link.pred$fit)
# 99% Wald CI
new$u1 <- res.pred$fit + res.pred$se.fit * qnorm(0.995)
new$l1 <- res.pred$fit - res.pred$se.fit * qnorm(0.995)
# 99% Wilson CI
new$u2 <- inv(link.pred$fit + link.pred$se.fit * qnorm(0.995)) 
new$l2 <- inv(link.pred$fit - link.pred$se.fit * qnorm(0.995))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(new, aes(leafHeight, fit)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = l1, ymax = u1), fill = NA, 
                  colour = "#6b4d8d", lty = 5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = l2, ymax = u2), fill = NA, 
                  colour = "#c7b300") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

As far as I understand it, the purple/dashed CI is a 99% Wald or normal approximation interval and the yellow/solid CI is a 99% Wilson score interval. I know that the Wald CI should be avoided due to the overshoot above 1 and below 0, which is clearly visible in the plot, [among other problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). However, the Wilson CI also doesn't look great. Despite the high (and, at $\alpha$ = 0.05, non-significant) *p* value of 0.06 for leafHeight and my choice of a 99% rather than 95% CI, it looks abnormally wide. I also tried this approach with my data, which fit the Cauchy CDF better and show a highly significant (*p* < 0.001) trend, and get a similarly wide CI.

So here are my questions:

1. Is the yellow/solid CI a correct 99% Wilson score interval around the predicted values of the `cauchit` GLM? [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/82724) suggests that a Wilson CI can be calculated with `binom::binom.confint(method = "wilson")`. However, I don't know how I could apply this `R` function to my example with a continuous predictor variable in order to check if it comes up with the same Wilson CI as is shown in the plot.
2. Would it be feasible to choose a Wald CI over a Wilson CI when the latter looks too wide, as is the case here, or when overshoot and zero-width are not apparent in the former?
3. Is there another easy way of calculating and plotting a CI for a binomial GLM with a `cauchit` link function? Are there other `R` packages I should know of?
4. I have used bootstrapped CIs in the past but don't know how to bootstrap binary data. How would I implement this in `R` in my case?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong.  Presumably, the wide intervals just reflect the limited amount of data you have and the non-significance of the slope at the 1% level.  As a sanity check, you could easily simulate from the fitted model, compute new confidence intervals based on simulated data and check if the coverage is approximately equal to the nominal level.