# Computing sample size for a sample to estimate binomial distribution when point estimate of proportion is 0

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, standard-error

For example, I have a estimate of p = 0 (95% CI: 0, 0.01), and I want to know the sample size for this sample.

For $p\not =0$, I can compute the s.e. by $\sqrt(p(1-p)/n)$ to get the $n$, but not sure how to compute $n$ in this case?

Comment: Does this post answer your question?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1

Comment: yes I think answer the first part, I edit my question to be specific to the second part

Comment: Do you know how the confidence interval was computed? If by the *rule of three*, as in the linked post, the upper limit is $\frac{1}{3n}$ and from there it s easy ...

Answer (score 1):

A Jeffreys 95% CI for the binomial proportion is based on
the non-informative prior distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5)$
and is said to give good frequentist results. Several other
styles of Cis are in common use. You should pick one that
does not rely directly on normal approximation.

For example, if $n = 50$ trials with $x = 10$ successes
then a a 95% CI for success probability $p$ is, then
the Agresti 95% CI $(0.919, 0.283)$ for $p$ is found as follows:

```
p.est = (12/64)
CI.agr = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/64)
CI.agr
[1] 0.09187523 0.28312477
```

The test-inverted Clopper-Pearson interval $(0.083, 0.285$ is available in the R procedure `binomon.test`:

```
binom.test(10, 60)

        Exact binomial test

data:  10 and 60
number of successes = 10, number of trials = 60, p-value = 1.616e-07
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.08292881 0.28521925
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
             0.1666667
```

And the Jeffreys' CI $(0.108, 0.326),$ based on a Bayesian argument with a non-informative prior, which is said to have good frequentist
properties, is found as by taking quantile $.025$ and $.975$
of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(.5+x, .5 + n - x)$ as follows.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), .5+10, .5+40)
[1] 0.1077340 0.3258269
```

Among these, I prefer the latter because of its properties
and ease of computation in R.

It provides one possible solution to your problem.
For $n = 61, x = 0,$ it gives the CI $(0, 0.04),$
as follows:

```
round(qbeta(c(.025,.975), .5, 61.5), 5)
[1] 0.00001 0.04018
```

It is easy to find $n = 61$ as a suitable sample
size by trial and error or by grid search with
values of $n$ from $1$ through $100.$ (I was looking for
an interval that gives $(0,0),$ when rounded to one decimal place.)

You might find @DavidLukeThiessen's suggested link
useful; also, the Wikipedia page on confidence
intervals for a binomial proportion.

With my answer
from the Jeffreys interval, you may want to compare
results for $n = 61$ from several other intervals.